# Protobuf in windows under MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, bash, protocol-buffers

Trying to compile and use google's protobuf in MinGW in windows - it is a dependency for a program I need to install.

I got the protobuf source and used msys' bash to run "configure", but the output from the configure hangs at a specific point.

```
protobuf-2.6.0>sh configure

checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking build system type... i686-pc-mingw32
checking host system type... i686-pc-mingw32
checking target system type... i686-pc-mingw32
checking for a BSD-compatible install... ./install-sh -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)...
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have another `make` program in your path that isn't the one from MSYS? Make sure MSYS' `make` takes priority.

Comment: I tried using the full path for the msys make, I do not think I have any other make program installed either.

Comment: @KentonVarda `sh which make` gives the msys path `/c/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make` which is correct. But when I do `sh make` it gives `sh: /c/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make: No such file or directory` ... No idea why! When I do `sh` followed by `make` my terminal hangs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @KentonVarda for pointing me in the right direction:
I came across the following: 
https://superuser.com/questions/581921/netbeans-mingw-c-file-not-found

What it states is:

- Go to C:\MinGW\bin and make a copy of mingw32-make.exe. Then rename it to make.exe
- Now go to C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin and rename make.exe to makeOLD.exe (just in case)
- Then move your new make.exe into C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin.